# Let $V$ be finite-dim and $T\in L(V; W)$. Then there exists a subspace $U$ of $V$ such that $U\cap{\rm Null}(T) = \{0\}$ and ${\rm Range}(T)= T(U)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been stuck for a while with this proof. I've looked up the answer but still don't really understand the thought process. If someone would be so kind as to explain to me this proof thoroughly and in simple words (English is not my native language), that would be amazing.

Suppose that $V$ is finite-dimensional and that $T\in L(V; W)$. Prove
that there exists a subspace $U$ of $V$ such that $U\cap \operatorname{Null}(T)= \{0\}$ and
$\operatorname{Range} T= \{T(u) : u\in U\}$.

Comment: Which is the proof you want exlained?

Comment: If $U$ is a complementary subspace of $Null(T)$, this means $V= Null(T) \oplus U$, then show that $U$ will do the job.

Comment: Hint : Take a basis $(b_{1},...,b_{k})$ for $Null(T)$ and complete it with vectors $b_{k+1},...,b_{n}$ to form a basis for $V$. Then check that $U=Span(b_{k+1},...,b_{n})$ is the subspace you seek.

Comment: @Fred I am fammiliar with that theorem but A direct sum of two subspaces doesn't automatically give V , the theorem is that  there exists for every subspace U a subspace V such that there direct sum = the ambient space but that doesn't make the direct sum of the subspaces always the ambient space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a basis $\{b_{1},...,b_{k}\}$ for $Null(T)$ and complete it with vectors $b_{k+1},...,b_{n}$ to form a basis for $V$. Let's check that $U=Span\{b_{k+1},...,b_{n}\}$ is the subspace we seek.

Let $\alpha \in U \cap Null(T)$, then $\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^k c_ib_i = \sum_{i=k+1}^n c_ib_i $ for some scalars $c_1,...,c_n$. This implies that $c_1=\ldots=c_n=0$ i.e. $\alpha =0$.

Define $Z=\{Tu : u \in U\}$. It is clear that $Z$ is a subspace of $V$ and that $Z \subset Range(T)$. Now let $\alpha \in Range(T)$, then $\alpha =T\beta$ for some $\beta \in V$, and $\beta = \sum_{i=1}^n c_ib_i$ for some scalars $c_1,...,c_n$. Then $\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^n c_iTb_i = \sum_{i=k+1}^n c_iTb_i = T(\sum_{i=k+1}^n c_ib_i)$ i.e $\alpha \in Z$ which gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set $\mathcal U$ of all subspaces $U\subseteq V$ with the property $U\cap \operatorname{Null}(T)=\{0\}$. For example, $\{0\}\in\mathcal U$, so $\mathcal U$ is not empty. Pick an element $U\in\mathcal U$ of maximal dimension and show that the range of $T$ is as desired.

Comment: Is it necessary to take subspace of the set of all subspace of V with maximal dimension ? Could you explain me why